# How to reduce my execution time in python when i am using print function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, numpy

So, When i am using `print()`/`sys.stdout.write()` to print my results (I have checked all the results are correct) the program execution time is increasing to min of 100times when i was not using print.

N = Number of elements in lists(`numpy` array)
C = C is an element of array
T = Number of Arrays

1≤N≤1000
1≤Ci≤10^5
1≤T≤100

**I am thinking this is happening because of print function. If yes How would I solve this issue**
**Without Print Execution time = 0.012797699999999967**
**With Print Execution time = 1.1667817**

**This is a question From Google KickStart**

````
def sub_one(inputlist, inputlength):
    smalllist = np.array([], dtype='int32')
    outputlist = np.array([], dtype='int32')
    h_score = 1
    for mainnum in inputlist:
        if mainnum > h_score:
            smalllist = np.append(smalllist, mainnum)
        else:
            outputlist = np.append(outputlist, mainnum)
            continue
        eachlist = np.array([], dtype='int32')
        for num in smalllist:
            if num >= h_score:
                eachlist = np.append(eachlist, h_score)
                if np.count_nonzero(eachlist) == h_score:
                    outputlist = np.append(outputlist, h_score)
                    smalllist = smalllist[smalllist > h_score]
                    h_score += 1
    

    return outputlist





def caseprinter(thelist):
    returnstring = ""
    for i in thelist:
        returnstring += (str(i) + " ")
    return returnstring



if __name__ == "__main__":
    cases = int(input())
    for i in range(cases):
        inputlength = int(input())
        inputlist = input().split(" ")
        inputlist = np.array(inputlist, dtype='int32')
        outputlist = sub_one(inputlist, inputlength)
        print(f'Case #{i+1}: {caseprinter(outputlist)}')```
````

Comment: Time to print is almost certainly slower than your numpy operations. Consider writing output to a file. Also, it would help if we could see your code

Comment: Yeah, how *are* you supposed to show your results? (I mean, what's the specification you were given for what to do?)

Comment: This a question from competitive programming and I am suppose to print it

Comment: Well, if printing is too slow and the website requires a huge amount of text to be printed then I would argue that either the website ask stupid things or your code use print functions in a definitively wrong way (eg. too many call). I guess the second case is the most probable. The thing is you did not provide your code so we cannot know if this is the case. You did not provide a link to the challenge either nor even a precise complete description... What did you expect from us?

Comment: Any Questions From Google Kickstart requires huge amount of printing, https://codingcompetitions.withgoogle.com/kickstart/round/00000000008f4332/0000000000941e56

Comment: I was trying to get this using threads still no results, If I store everything in a variable and prints everything at the end or I print one case at a time doesnot matter it always taking 450-490 seconds

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your

```
def caseprinter(thelist):
    returnstring = ""
    for i in thelist:
        returnstring += (str(i) + " ")
    return returnstring
```

might take quadratic time. Try linear time:

```
def caseprinter(thelist):
    return " ".join(map(str, thelist))
```

Comment: Its Kind Of Helping cause it is reducing the time from 480 to 380

Comment: @Snehasisbasu Seconds? I thought you said it takes 0.012 or 1.2 seconds. Or what did you mean with those numbers in the question?

Comment: yes seconds time.pref_counter () measures seconds only, Its a good reduction of time your suggestion works